# My code keeps getting this error: return statement in a function get or operator must return a value

Tags: vb.net

Here's my code:

```
Public Function score()
    Dim file As System.IO.FileStream
    Dim Form As String

    If Form = 1 Then
        Try

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Users\sfawcett\Documents\savedquizdata\class1.txt") Then
                Return

            End If


            file = System.IO.File.Create("C:\Users\sfawcett\Documents\savedquizdata\class1.txt")
            file.Close()
            Dim addInfo As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\sfawcett\Documents\savedquizdata\class1.txt")

            addInfo.WriteLine("The person-->" & Name & "<-- got a score of " & score() & " out of 10 from class " & Form)
            addInfo.Close()
        Catch
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: Well...you should heed the advice of the error, and *return* something.

Comment: show your function signature. what is it suppose to return?

Comment: What they said. You have "return" and then nothing. It needs to return like "return "thisisastring" "

Comment: You should also turn on Option Strict, it will require you to declare what type the function returns.  if it returns nothing, change it to a Sub

Comment: Also add Option Strict On to the top of your code file or set it in your project's properties.  Your function signature should have a return type specified.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a method that doesn't return anything, you need to use `Sub` instead of `Function`, e.g. `Public Sub score()`...

Otherwise, if you intend to return something, you can do that in two ways: you can set the implicit return variable, which is the function's name, to your return value:

`Score=123`

Or you can use the `Return` keyword with a value:

`Return 123`.

Additionally, as Tim points out, a function that doesn't have a return type (e.g. `Scope() As Integer`) assumes a type of `Object`, and thus all values obtained from your function would have to be cast accordingly.

Comment: It's important to note that  in VB.NET a method returns `Object` if it doesn't have an `As ReturnType` at the end of the signature. So the return-type is optional. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx): _"A Function procedure can declare the data type of the value that the procedure returns. You can specify any data type or the name of an enumeration, a structure, a class, or an interface. If you don't specify the returntype parameter, the procedure returns Object."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter -- Of course, thanks Tim, I've updated my answer to include this.